# Localstorage doesn't work on my Todo list Angular

Tags: angularjs

I found this localstorage code from another side, but i tried to put it on my own code, which doesn't work. If i refresh my site, i can see the number of the todo list, but the list it self is gone?

How someone explain me, what is wrong? :)

Btw my controller is on my starting body tag:

```
    <main>
        <h1>What to do today?</h1>

        <div class="container">

            <span>{{ remaining() }} of {{ todos.length }} remaining</span>

            <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
                <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" placeholder="Add a new todo" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Add new list" >
            </form>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                    <span ng-bind="todo.todoText"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <button ng-click="remove()">Clear completed</button>

        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <h3>Winkel Design a/s</h3>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script>
            var app = angular.module('TodoApp', []);
            app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('todos');
                $scope.todos = (localStorage.getItem('todos')!==null) ? JSON.parse($scope.saved) : [{todoText:'Clean your room', done:false}];
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));

                $scope.addTodo = function() {
                    $scope.todos.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
                    $scope.todoInput = "";
                    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));
                };

                $scope.remove = function() {
                    $scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function(item){
                        return !item.done
                    });
                };

                $scope.remaining = function() {
                    var count = 0;
                    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo){
                        count+= todo.done ? 0 : 1;
                    });
                    return count;
                };

                $scope.archive = function() {
                    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
                    $scope.todos = [];
                    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo){
                        if (!todo.done)
                            $scope.todos.push(todo);
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));
                };

            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't inject `localStorage` into `controller`. I assume, you are using third party application for it. You should use [`angular-local-storage`](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) instead.

Comment: Is there another way around without using third party applikation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JeDbsLLAgAx3TFcO364B?p=preview)

It seems, your code works fine except `ng-repeat` directive. I had to add `track by $index`, and everything works fine now, as far as I can see.

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
    <span ng-bind="todo.todoText"></span>
</li>
```

From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.
>
> For example, you may track items by the index of each item in the collection, using the special scope property $index:

Also, I recommend you to use angular module, like [`angular-local-storage`](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), which will fallback to cookies, in case browser doesn't support localStorage API.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now!
I will try to take a look at angular-local-storage!

Have a nice day :)

Comment: @JonasWinkel I would appreciate if you approved/upvoted my answer. It is how stack overflow works, mate ;-)

Comment: Hehe thanks, always used this site for information, but never posted anything :D